# Android: Browser back button will not fire $getJSON event

Tags: android, browser, button, getjson, back

I have a test project that uses $getJSON to pull data from web services like Geonames and our own proprietary services.  The index page uses two $getJSON calls, and they load fine both when you first load the page or press the refresh.  However, if you navigate to another page and then hit the back button to go back to the index page, the page begins reloading and just stops when it hits the $getJSON calls. I've read about Android browser not caching well with the back button in 2.1 (what I'm using)- I'm fine with page reloads as long as it actually completely loads the page.

I've tried this in Firefox and it caches the index page, so there's no re-running of the JSON calls.  That's why I'm asking it here in an Android capacity- is it purely the no-caching back button thing that is the problem or is there something I could change about my $getJSON calls?

Here's the page:
http://MPulsemobile.info

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that the Android browser does not report events for the back button like other browsers.

Imagine you have a form containing a text field, and the text field contains, say, 3 characters.

Create a JavaScript alert that will fire on `keyup()` and begin deleting characters.  The alert will not fire until the final key up.

Comment: How about having old forms lying around in the DOM?  Any ideas there studiobl?